# Add JQuery variable to $('.class').html("HTML");

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to isolate one element by it's class but I need part of the class name to be from a variable as every element has a unique name.

```
div class="post6453"
div class="post9845"
div class="post2345"

var id = $(this).attr("id"); (ID = 6453, 9845, 2345 for example)

if(data == 1){
            $('post+ID').html("Html goes here");
            }else{
            $('post+ID').html("Html goes here");
            }
```

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: A selector is just a string, so you can use *string concatenation* to build the selector dynamically. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your variable is `id` (lowercase) and not `ID`. Even your variable concatenation is not correct. Try with

```
$('.post' + id).html(...)
```

Comment: I'm only using ID here as an example. But this code worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

if element is unique you should use ID="" instead :

i think this is the jQuery selector

```
$(".post"+id).html("Html goes here");
```